# Errors with Material UI AppBar

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am building a student project. I have tried several times to incorporate Material UI into my project but have had no success. For instance, I am attempting to add "App Bar with Menu" linked [here](https://mui.com/components/app-bar/#main-content). I have installed `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled @material-ui/icons` in React, and copied the code exactly from MUI's example into its own component in my project, but am receiving the following errors:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/components/MenuAppBar/MenuAppBar.js 12:0-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Menu' in '/home/michael/flatiron/phase-5/project-template/frontend/src/components/MenuAppBar'


ERROR in ./src/components/MenuAppBar/MenuAppBar.js 13:0-62

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle' in '/home/michael/flatiron/phase-5/project-template/frontend/src/components/MenuAppBar'
```

What am I missing? I don't see any documentation on this AppBar that would tell me I have to install something other than what I've installed, and I pulled up three youtube videos which simply show the user copying the code into a component, as I've done.

Comment: You need to install npm install @mui/icons-material

Comment: Thank you. I had @material-ui/icons installed but it was not clear to me that I also/instead needed @mui/icons-material